# Setting the Color of a TextView Drawable

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im trying to change the color of a TextView Drawable in Xamarin.

In Java you can do it like this:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    TextView txt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_textview);
    setTextViewDrawableColor(txt, R.color.my_color);
}

private void setTextViewDrawableColor(TextView textView, int color) {
    for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawables()) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(getColor(color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }
    }
}
```

How i can do something like this in Xamarin.Android?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Try below solution

```
private void setTextViewDrawableColor(TextView textView, int color) {
        for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawables()) {
            if (drawable != null) {
                drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(), color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: those also might help if someone want to convert resource color to android color: new Android.Graphics.Color (ContextCompat.GetColor (this, Resource.Color.bb_orange) and Color.ParseColor("#000000");

Comment: This works for me `drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(resColorBlack, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));`

Comment: For anyone looking to do this in Java: `yourTextView.getCompoundDrawables()[0].setTint(getResources().getColor(R.color.red));`

Answer (score 48):

I am using this in kotlin:

```
tv.getCompoundDrawables()[0].setTint(//color)
```

Comment: I would do: tv.getCompoundDrawables()[0]?.setTint(//color)

Comment: should be the answer!

Comment: This allows us to set the tint for API levels below **M**. Thank you!

Comment: Simple and you can apply foreach to make all drawbles the same if you use them all.

Answer (score 38):

Please, notice that if you set drawables in your layout file via `android:drawableStart` or `android:drawableEnd` instead of `android:drawableLeft` and `android:drawableRight` respectively you should use [TextView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#getCompoundDrawablesRelative()). Otherwise you can get empty array of drawables.

```
private void setTextViewDrawableColor(TextView textView, int color) {
    for (Drawable drawable : textView.getCompoundDrawablesRelative()) {
        if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.setColorFilter(new PorterDuffColorFilter(ContextCompat.getColor(textView.getContext(), color), PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Very interesting, I was doing this tinting in a RecyclerView and it wasn't reliable. With compoundDrawablesRelative it seems to be fine.

Answer (score 19):

```
// index of drawable
val left = 0
val start = left
val top = 1
val right = 2
val end = right
val bottm = 3

// color int
val color = Color.RED

// apply tint for target drawable
textView.compoundDrawables.getOrNull(left)?.setTint(color)

// apply tint for all drawables
textView.compoundDrawables?.forEach { it?.setTint(color) }
```

**NOTE!**

if in XML layout you use `android:stratDrawable` or `android:endDrawable` you have to work with `textView.compoundDrawablesRelative` array, `textView.compoundDrawables` contains drawables when they have been added with `android:leftDrawable` or `android:rightDrawable` attributes.

Comment: If compoundDrawables are null try compoundDrawablesRelative

Answer (score 13):

There's built in support for this through `TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawableTintList(textView, colors)`

```
val color = ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.foo)
val colorList = ColorStateList.valueOf(color)
TextViewCompat.setCompoundDrawableTintList(textView, colorList)
```

Answer (score 11):

I solve this problem adding in xml definition this line:

> android:drawableTint="@color/red"

A complete example:

> ```
>         <TextView
>             android:id="@+id/tv_element"
>             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
>             android:layout_height="20dp"
>             android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
>             android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_icon"
>             android:drawableTint="@color/color"
>             android:visibility="visible" />
> ```

Answer (score 5):

I faced the problem where I am changing the color of the compound drawable and except one rest of all the colors are constant. Confusing for me.!!!

the solution that worked for me is

```
// Pass through the each drawable and update the tint if drawable is set.
textView.compoundDrawables.filterNotNull().forEach { drawable ->
        drawable.mutate()
        drawable.setTint(drawableColor)
    }
```

Without the `mutate()`, the things were working partially. I got the more details here [Drawable Mutations](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/05/drawable-mutations.html#:%7E:text=For%20convenience%2C%20mutate()%20returns,us%20at%20Google%20I%2FO.) .

For the interest of the reader, I am providing a quick summery below.

Android Drawables are the drawing containers. Such as BitmapDrawable is used to display the images, ShapeDrawable is used to display the shapes and gradients.

`Drawables are used extensively in the Android ecosystem thus they are optimized. So when views are created the different instances are spawned but the drawables associated with the view share the common state, called "Constant state".`

For example, if a drawable is a BitmapDrawable then the same bitmap is used with the all the corresponding copies or views.

Advantage: It simply saves huge amount of memory.

*Problem*: As the same drawable is shared across the various views. Any change in the state of the drawable such as alpha, transformation etc. will impact all the places where it is used.

*Solution*: The mutate() method when called on a drawable, the constant state of the drawable is duplicated to allow you to change any property without affecting other drawables. Note: Bitmap is still shared.

Answer (score 4):

For `Kotlin`. Use the below extension for the `TextView` drawable. It supports below and above API level of 23.

```
    private fun TextView.setTextViewDrawableColor(color: Int) {
        for (drawable in this.compoundDrawablesRelative) {
            drawable?.mutate()
            drawable?.colorFilter = PorterDuffColorFilter(
                color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
            )
        }
    }
```

Note: You can also use this function in the `RecyclerView` item as well, It will not `override` the same color for each item

Comment: Not working....

Comment: use it instead tv.getCompoundDrawables()[0]?.setTint(//color)

Answer (score 3):

If you want to change the tint color of the drawable of any view (tested on API 29) :

```
private fun setTintColor(textView: TextView, color: Int) {

    DrawableCompat.setTint(DrawableCompat.wrap(textView.background).mutate(), 
    ContextCompat.getColor(this, color))

}
```

Comment: Why the `mutate()` call is important: _By default, all drawables instances loaded from the same resource share a common state; if you modify the state of one instance, all the other instances will receive the same modification._

Answer (score 1):

I create extension like this

```kotlin
fun TextView.setDrawableTintExt(color: Any) {
    
    when (color) {
        is String -> {
            for (drawable in this.compoundDrawables) {
                if (drawable != null) {
                    drawable.colorFilter =
                        PorterDuffColorFilter(
                            getHexColorExt(color),
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
                        )
                }
            }
        }
        
        is Int -> {
            for (drawable in this.compoundDrawables) {
                if (drawable != null) {
                    drawable.colorFilter =
                        PorterDuffColorFilter(
                            ContextCompat.getColor(this.context, color),
                            PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN
                        )
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```